# Fastest way to capture server screen in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vnc

I'm building something like Amblilight and I need to capture the screen (1920x1080) as fast as possible and process it to get colors for LEDs.

I'm using Node.js as programming language. I tried to capture screen using VNC protocol (using my own client impementation), but it gave me like 1 FPS and there was delay like 3 seconds. I need fastest way to capture the screen of the computer, which runs node.js.

I'm using Ubuntu-based linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be difficult to answer because screen capturing is system dependent. If I were going to write this type of thing for my current system on MacOSX, I would utilize the command line for taking a screen shot.

```
//from Terminal
>screencapture ~/Desktop/test.png
```

Then incorporate this into Node.JS:

```
//screenshot.js

var file = '~/Desktop/test.png';
var worker = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');

worker.exec('screencapture ' + file, function(err, results) {
  if(err) return console.error(err);

  //process image
  var imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(file);

  while(imageBuffer.read()) {
   //process lines in buffer
  }
});
```

Comment: I already tried something like this, but it was slow. I need something like 5 FPS. I edited my question with info about my OS.